# Openlayers - select only one feature and disable the rest

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a WFS layer:

```
var sourceVector = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
          return 'http://myserver:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
              'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=mygroup:mylayer&' +
              'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&';
        },
});

var layerVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: sourceVector
});
```

I have a interaction select for the features:

```
var interactionSelect = new ol.interaction.Select({

    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#EAEA1A'
        })
    })
});
```

And, programmatically I selected one feature:

```
var listenerKey = sourceVector.on('change', function(e) {
  if (sourceVector.getState() == 'ready') {
    interactionSelect.getFeatures().clear() 
    interactionSelect.getFeatures().push(sourceVector.getFeatureById('mylayer.1853'))
    map.addInteraction(interactionSelect);

  }
});
```

How can I leave that feature already selected and disable the other features from the same wfs layer? I did this way so far because there's only one feature selected at the beginning, but also I want to let the user modify that feature, but it has to be that particular feature; with this code above, the user gets the feature selected in red but he can select other features

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to modify a subset of the features of a source, what you can do is set `features` property instead of `source` of the modify interaction. In that way you control which are the features that can be modified.

Take a look at the example I made for you. It uses the countries.geojson source of OL. I pick `Uruguay` as the only feature that can be modified.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css"
    type="text/css">
  <style>
    .map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  <title>OpenLayers example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

    var modifyFeatures = new ol.Collection();

    var source = new ol.source.Vector({
      url: 'https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
      wrapX: false
    });

    source.on('change', function(e) {
      if (source.getState() === 'ready') {
        var feature = source.getFeatures().find(f => f.get('name') === 'Uruguay'); 
        modifyFeatures.push(feature);
      }
    });

    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source
    });

    var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
      wrapX: false
    });

    var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
      features: modifyFeatures
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
      interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([select, modify]),
      layers: [raster, vector],
      target: 'map',
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-55.75, -32.85]),
        zoom: 6
      })
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```